# Read only selected lines of a .txt file according to values specified in other variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe in .txt file format called `mat.txt` of dimension 900*3, with column headers being V1, V2, and V3. These 900 rows contain information from 100 participants (`ID`), where each participant's information corresponds to 9 rows. The 9 rows of each participant is further dividied into 3 elements with each element repeated 3 times (`ele`).

This generates toy data:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1234)
mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(900 * 3), ncol = 3))
fwrite(mat, "mat.txt")

ID <- rep(1:100, each = 9)
ele <- rep(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 100)
```

The first element of ID and ele corresponds to information associated with the first row of mat. The same applies to other rows. I want to **load ONLY rows of the `mat.txt` that corresponds to all individuals' ele 2**. The result should be a dataframe of 300*3. How to do this in R?

**Note that I do not want to load the entire .txt file first and then subset the data** since my real data is too large to be loaded into R at once. Something like readLines in for loop seems should be used, but I just cannot figure out how. Please try to ensure the suggested code to be as general as possible. By general, I mean when I translate the code to my real large dataset, I do not have to gone through some painful manual editing work. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried libraries like `vroom` to read your data? That package doesn't read the data into memory right away, it more or less creates an index of where line breaks occur so you can read in data more directly. If `mat.txt` contains data in text form, you need to scan for every new-line character to find rows. You can't really jump to certain records without reading all the data before it. If you stored data in a fixed-width binary format, it would be easier to just read parts of the data.

Comment: Could you pls provide an example of vroom for the is question'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `scan` which allows to provide a `skip` and `nlines`, then split the lines and bind it all together.

**update** *added the "ele" to select*

```
# interpretted those from your data and description
replications <- 100
each <- 9
repeats <- 3
selected_ele <- 2

con <- file("mat.txt")

library(data.table)

rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(replications), \(i) {
  transpose(strsplit(scan(con, what = "numeric", skip = (i - 1) * each + 1 + (selected_ele - 1) * repeats, nlines = repeats), ","))
}))[, lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
```

Comment: I save results of `rbindlist` to `tmp`. The first row of `tmp` should correspond to the 4th row the mat.txt since the 4th element of `ele` is the first time of `ele` bing 2. However, `tmp` row 1 != row 4 of mat.txt. Any ideas?

Comment: I see I took my example with ele being 1, I assumed you can easily adapt my solution for any ele as it simply shifts 3 per increment of ele

Comment: added the option to select the ele

Comment: Getting very close but still need some tweak. Currently, row 1-3 of column 1  of `tmp` are row 1 of mat.txt. I want column 1-3 of row 1 of `tmp` to be row 1 of mat.txt. Same rule for the rest of `tmp`. Just pick relevant rows from mat.txt but do not transpose each selected 3*3 part. Would be much appreciated if the code could be updated.

Comment: fixed the issue with transposed data

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. Just note that `selected` in your updates should be `selected_ele` to be consistent with your specification. I asked the same question several days ago in ChatGPT but the answer has never been correct.